# Most pythonic way to count a specific string in a space separated string in a list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like `['$25 million', '$22 million', '$3.3 billion']` and I want to count how many times million, billion show up.

I am using the script below that works but I wonder if it is the most pythonic way.

```
million = 0
billion = 0
not_mb = 0
for price in money_lower:
  if price.split().count('million') > 0:
    million += 1
  elif price.split().count('billion') > 0:
    billion += 1
  else: not_mb += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.Counter` is your best bet for things like this. You'll need to preprocess the list to extract the million/billion.

```
>>> collections.Counter(item.split()[1] for item in money_lower)
Counter({'million': 2, 'billion': 1})
```

(Note, this is more elegant than your solution, but not more efficient, since it requires two passes over the data.)

Comment: I chose this as the best answer because I had made a poor assumption of my data and this actually found an error I had 15k entries in the list and one of them was "the hundreds of millions of dollars"

Answer (score 2):

You can also join list to string and use [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
money_lower = ['$25 million', '$22 million', '$3.3 billion']

money_lower = ''.join(money_lower)
million = money_lower.count('million') 
billion = money_lower.count('billion')

print(million)  # 2
print(billion)  # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst all of the other answers are definitely very *pythonic* and *elegant*, it's not always the most important thing to strive for. Your original code is actually the only one so far to go over the list *once*. I'd maybe simplify it just a tad:

```
for price in money_lower:
  if 'million' in price: million += 1
  elif 'billion' in price: billion += 1
```

Otherwise your code is easy to read and performant (counts with a single pass).

Comment: this is a great one to simplify my script as well thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pick the elements of the list `money_lower` which contain specificic words *(such as `million` or `billion`)* as follows;

```
money_lower = ['$25 million', '$22 million', '$3.3 billion']

million =  [m for m in money_lower if "million" in m]
billion =  [b for b in money_lower if "billion" in b]
```

Now you have 2 lists(*million,billion*) which contains the targeted elements of the `money_lower` list. If you want to learn how many elements in the lists, you can use the `len()` function as follows;

```
print("Count of the string million: ", len(million))
```